# Unable to deploy on real devices in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My project builds successfully, but when the project is deployed into the device I'm unable to debug the application. I've tried:

- deleting **bin**, **obj**
- restarting application.

But I'm still unable to debug.

This is the output:

> C:\Users\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK\tools\lint.bat
>    --quiet --disable "UnusedResources,HardcodedDebugMode" --resources obj\Debug\res\ obj\Debug\
>
> "lint.bat" exited with code 1.
>
> Done building project "project.csproj". Build succeeded. An error
>   occured. See full exception on logs for more details. "lint.bat"
>   exited with code 1.
>
> ========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: It seems to be failing at linting or similar. Try to disable this temporarily. Also, please include a full diagnostic build output to your post.

Comment: Thank for your info can u tell me how to disable this.?

Comment: Attach a diagnostic build output and your .csproj.

Answer (score 0):

Is Lint is enabled in your application ?

```
<AndroidLintEnabled>true</AndroidLintEnabled >
```

the android lint tool will be run and the warnings/errors will be output as normal xbuild/msbuild errors and warnings.

Clear the lint errors / warnings and try again.

If you fail to fix the errors try disable the lint  `<AndroidLintEnabled>false</AndroidLintEnabled >` and try

Check this [link](https://onestopdotnet.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/xamarin-vs-2015-break-the-error-message-into-chunks/) this may help you.

Comment: Thanks janmejoy...I will try

Comment: I'll let you know once I check

Comment: It's working but after small modifications in options as changing verbosity options to Diagnostics